# Do something with sequence of cells in an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, sum, range, sequence

I want to [sum](/questions/tagged/sum) "every 5th row between A9 and A54," i.e.

> A(5x + 9)-A(54),

inside [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

There's also a sub-question here. Is it possible to sum a [range](/questions/tagged/range) of cells using a function or VBA?

Here are some test questions, based on the answer:

- `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range))+1,1)=0),A1:A50)`--sums row A1 throughA50?
- `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A50)-MIN(ROW(A50))+1,2)=0),A1:A50)`--sums every other row, A1 through A50
- `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A5:A50)-MIN(ROW(A1:A50))+1,5)=0),A1:A50)`--sums everyth 5th row between A5 and A50?

Based on:

> Substitute A9:A54 for Range and 5 for n for your specific query. Only
>   those parts change Answer will remain the same even if you delete rows
>   below Range.

Comment: What do you mena by "get" - select every 5th cell?

Comment: Something like `=--(MOD(ROW($A$9:$A$54)-8,5)=0)` would give you a `1` every fifth row and `0` for the rest, but I'll piggyback on @brettdj's question - select or use?

Comment: @brettdj I'm trying to insert them into a function

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? Have you used the macro recorder to build some VBA to look at?

Comment: @MikeWoodhouse I was actually in a meeting with a client.  I'll be trying these things right now.  What I'm finding is that I don't understand the syntax I'm being given.  I need to take things step-by-step.  First, I need to figure out how to code in `sum column a rows 1-8`; then, `sum column a rows 2-8`; then, `sum column a rows 2, 4, 6, 8`; then, `sum rows 4, 6, 8` (which should be clear at that point), for example.

Comment: @RocketDonkey Can you please explain the grammar in an answer?  I'm not sure, for example, what `-8,5` do, or where to read about this, or what the significance of the `=0` is.  Say, for example, I want to `sum 1, 2, 3, ... 50` and then `sum 5, 10, 15, ..., 50`, and finally `sum 10, 15, 20, ..., 50`?  If you submit what you're saying in clear terms, I imagine it qualifies as an answer; so, you may as well submit it as an answer.

Comment: My answer would have been the same as what Barry had below. Basic idea is to use `MOD` (modulo) to take a given row and divide it by 5, and if the result is 0, 'include' it in our range (in this case, it means giving it a value of 1). `SUMPRODUCT` is used to multiply arrays together, so you then take your array of 0's and 1's and multiply it by all of the values in that column (this means that 1's (every fifth row) are multiplied by the number in that row, while everything else is 0). The result is then summed, and you get your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a more robust version of RocketDonkey's answer. The -8 in his comment is because the first row of the range is 9 but generically for any single column range you can use this formula to sum every nth row (starting with the first row of the range)

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range)),n)=0),Range)`

Substitute A9:A54 for Range and 5 for n for your specific query. Only those parts change

Answer will remain the same even if you delete rows below Range

**Explanation**

The part ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range)) will return an array of integers, starting with 0 through the number of integers corresponds to the number of cells in the range, so

`=ROW(A9:A54)-MIN(ROW(A9:A54))`

produces this array

`{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45}`

When you feed that in to MOD function with divisor 5 then clearly MOD(0,5) = 0, so the first cell (A9) in this case, always satisfies the condition.....and so with every 5th (or nth) cell in the range so

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A9:A54)-MIN(ROW(A9:A54)),5)=0),A9:A54)`

sums every 5th cell starting with the first cell in the range, i.e. it sums A9, A14, A19, A24....etc.

Clearly you could replace MIN(ROW(A9:A54)) with 9 but then if you delete some rows below row 9 the formula results will change so using that construction is a little more robust

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - this is what I was about to type, so I'd go with this. (+1 as well :) )

Comment: What's the significance of `+1` in the answer: `MIN(ROW(Range))+1`?

Comment: The reasons I ask, btw, are because a) I'm at a PC without Excel, and I won't have won't be at one for two days; and b) for answer eloquence, to assist future readers and get you thumbed.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up, +1 shouldn't be there, I'll edit that and explain in my question.....

Comment: @barryhoudini Actually, it's still a little unclear to me because `MIN(ROW(A9:A54)` should return the lowest value of the rows between A9 and A54, right?  So if you have `5, 10, 4, 20, 1`: `1` should be the output of `MIN(ROW(A1:A5)`, right?

Comment: @barryhoudini why the `-` (minus) sign?  You modulate....  You get the lowest row number, which is 9... and subtract it from 54?

Comment: MIN(ROW(A9:A54)) doesn't look at the cell values at all, it just gets the lowest row number in that range - in this case 9. The idea is to "normalise" the row labelling so that the first row is "labelled" zero [ using ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range)) ] and every subsequent row increments by 1 - by using that formulation it doesn't matter what the range is, first cell is always labelled zero, so MOD(0,n) will always give you zero, so first cell is always included in the sum and every subsequent nth cell

Comment: @barryhoudini It's kind of a weird trick because I don't see its value.  Why is it so important to always start with 0?

Comment: @barryhoudini Still wondering why `negative` (`negative 8 or 9`) and why `=0`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `ROW(A9:A54)-MIN(ROW(A9:A54)` in `MOD(ROW(A9:A54)-MIN(ROW(A9:A54)),5` produces the number -9.  In this equation, MOD, the value of x in -x is the location on the number line away from `cell 0`.  So, the result of `ROW(A9:A54)-MIN(ROW(A9:A54)`, `-9`, makes A9 the 0th entry in the array we run `MOD` over.  It's possible that's what the `=0` is for....

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(-9,5)),A9:A54)` apparently has the same effect.  For some reason, the long version is preferred, which is: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range)),n)=0),Range)`.  I don't see the advantage, but it has something to do with either shifting or deleting cells.  I imagine it's shifting because having an empty cell shouldn't matter.

I'm also a bit perplexed as to why we use `=SUMPRODUCT` and not `SUM` and `--` rather than `SUM`.  `--` does addition, and it also converts bools to numbers, I guess.  I don't see why either of those things would be necessary, here.  Perhaps it's a just-in-case thing.  For example, perhaps every 15th row is an undesired string constant, rather than a desired number.  I think that it would be more universally useful to just enclose one series within another, in that case, though.